# Activity Monitor (Program Time Tracker)

Tags: time, monitor

I am searching for a nice Windows (also Mac?) tool to monitor the time a user spent in each programme. The program shouldn't count the time the program is opened but the time the program is active (active usage). I also need to have access to the data.

The [Personal Activity Monitor](http://activitymonitor.codeplex.com/) would perfectly fit my needs, but it unfortunately is very unstable. I also tried [Wamon](http://code.google.com/p/wamon/), but I found no way to access the data programatically besides the website that is offered...

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now managed to do with Wamon what I wanted. :)
The data is stored in a SQLight DB under C:\ProgramData.

Answer (score 2):

I created my own Program Monitor as a project to learn Azure. The client runs on Windows and all information is uploaded to Azure Table Storage. It is created based on what I wanted. Some of these requirements will turn some people off - a gmail account is required for login (I didn't want to remember another password). Obviously all your information is also logged to the 'cloud' which can also be undesirable. Anyhow it's free and I have ran it for 2 months with no crashes - it is very stable.

The url is http://waidmonitor.com. There's a feedback form after you log in too if there's anything you'd really like to see in it.

Comment: Hi @Marksl! I am trying to understand how this kind of application works! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583568/determine-which-software-is-being-used-by-the-windows-mac-user-using-a-java-appl. What kind of language you are using to do this?

Comment: My application is written in C#. I currently only support Windows so I used several Win32 methods. This is how you can poll to see if the user is pressing keys or moving the mouse: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx . This is how you can see what application the user is using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117851/how-can-i-determine-the-current-focused-process-name-and-version-in-c-sharp. I believe you can use JNA to call Win32 dlls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389156/calling-win32-api-method-from-java

Comment: Any consideration to releasing this open source?  I would love to see the code and tinker.

Comment: Sure. I threw it up on github. Here it is  https://github.com/marksl/waid